# Error while executing a stored procedure to drop a table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Getting error while executing a stored procedure that drops a table.

I have compiled the procedure successfully (used dynamic SQL for the code).
Tool used is SQL Developer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_DROP(P_VAR IN VARCHAR2)
IS 
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE'||P_VAR;  -- passing table via parameter
END;
```

but I'm getting error while executing this procedure:

```
EXECUTE sp_DROP('CON1'); -- i have made sure CON1 is a legit table.
```

Error :

> ORA-00950: invalid DROP option
>   ORA-06512: at "HR.SP_DROP", line 4
>   ORA-06512: at line 3
>   00950. 00000 -  "invalid DROP option"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Thanks for the help.

Comment: do you include a whitespace at the beginning of `P_VAR`? otherwise you are missing one since there is none after the `'DROP TABLE'`

Comment: yes, it was the white space. thank you for the help.

Comment: Run the query select * from dba_objects where object_name = '<TABLE_NAME>' and share the results.

Answer (score 1):

Add a space to the end of drop table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_DROP(P_VAR IN VARCHAR2)
IS 
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '||P_VAR;  -- passing table via parameter
END;
```